# Jquery mobile on iOS - momentum scroll prevents click handler being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

Basically as the title sounds.

If I implement overflow-scrolling touch, i.e. the native-like momentum scrolling on iOS any click fails to register during the "deceleration" phase of the scroll. Is there are reason for this? Or a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

Mobile Safari does not synthesize a `click` event from touches registered during scroll events. If you want to listen to a touch event, register handlers for them: `touchstart`, `touchend`, `touchmove`, etc

Caveat: I use jQuery extensively, jQuery mobile not at all, so if there are differences in event handling behavior around click synthesis, this answer does not reflect that.

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/noyer/2/edit

- Load the page in Mobile Safari
- See "Console" panel for a log of the events being captured
- See "JavaScript" panel for event handling code

First, tap the "Output" panel without scrolling, and notice that the events propagated are:

- `touchstart`: Finger taps the panel
- `touchend`: Finger releases the panel
- `mousedown`: Safari synthesized event
- `mouseup`: Safari synthesized event
- `click`: Safari synthesized event

Now scroll the "Output" panel, then tap it to stop the scroll, and notice that the events propagated are:

- `touchstart`: Finger taps the panel to start the drag
- A cycle of `touchmove` and `scroll` events representing finger dragging the panel and the panel scrolling in response
- `touchend`: Finger releases the panel
- Some number of `scroll` events representing the panel scrolling with momentum
- `touchstart`: Finger taps the panel to stop the scroll
- `scroll`: If the event gets fired, represents the scroll decelerating
- `touchend`: Finger releases the panel

Hope this helps.

Comment: Makes sense thanks, great explanation and example. Not quite sure about the best way to solve the issue now. Bind to the touchend event?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to accomplish. If you want to see something as soon as the user touches, use `touchstart`, but be aware that they may be "flicking" to continue or accelerate the scroll. If you want to ensure that the event is a touch that stops a scroll, you'll have to statefully manage the `scroll` and `touch(start|end)` events, again depending on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Sorry, I've only just seen this. Basically what is happening is that the click on the navbar at the bottom of the page doesn't work if the content is still "decelerating". The click/touch of the navbar simply stops the deceleration. This is inside of jquery mobile v1.4